# How clear my YouTube playlist via API? (delete all playlistitems, but not delete playlist)

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

How clear my YouTube playlist via API? Need delete all playlistitems, but not delete playlist.
Of course I know - need loop for 1. get playlistinem ID 2. delete it 3. etc 
But may be is simpler way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its documented in Youtube API. Here's the flow that you should follow to delete the playListItems.
Get the list of plaListItems from PlayList.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list - use List

After you get a list of items from your playlist use the "DELETE playListItem"
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete

Comment: I get error "Login Required." even though I provide an API key. I haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: For login just use client side to test. Ensure that your scopes are defined. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting the playlist, then recreating it. The following is Kotlin code and mYouTube is an authenticated youtube object as per the API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

```
// Delete the playlist
mYouTube.playlists().delete({playlistId}).execute()

// Create a new playlist
val playlist = Playlist()

playlist.snippet = PlaylistSnippet()
playlist.snippet.title = {playlist title}
playlist.status = PlaylistStatus()

mYoutube.playlists().insert("snippet,status", playlist).execute()
```

Comment: That also resets the view count to zero.